# WP8 - LongListSelector "delay" issue

Tags: c#, objective-c, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I am actually facing a little issue concerning a LongLingSelector object in C# (WP8).

The string I am working on is the following:

`string tmpText = ((Storico)Storico.SelectedItem).Name;`

where (Storico) is the class and Storico is the LongListSelector XAML object.

What I currently need is that, when the user presses an item of the list, I subsequentially get its name in the tmpText string.

What I am currently getting, instead, is the following:

let's suppose I have 3 items in my list:

```
item1
item2
item3
```

I press item 1, nothing happens.
I press item 2, I get item 1 name.
I press item 1, I get item 2 name (and that goes on over and over, also with item3 of course).

Any way to fix that?

Thanks in advance!

Full code is here :)

```
private void Storico_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {
            if (Storico.SelectedItem is Storico)
            {
                  string tmpText = ((Storico)Storico.SelectedItem).Name;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you show the code? You probably do something wrong when the selection changes. For instance, when pressing item1, that item gets selected but since no other item was selected first, the SelectionChanged event doesn't get raised.

Comment: code placed in the main question :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed! I actually was checking the tap event on the Button in the LongListSelector. I changed it to check the LongListSelector, instead, and I got it fixed!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if your project is already using MVVM, but if it does... you can use following Behaviour - http://www.spikie.be/blog/post/2014/01/10/.aspx to get access to the selected item!

A complete explanation on what is 'odd' with the current LongListSelector and how to counter it, can be found on the Nokia Developer site here: http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/LongListSelector_with_bindable_SelectedItem_and_better_scrolling